# Running a jquery script in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to use a similar script to the one is WordPress but it will not work and I know it's something to do with the way WordPress leads / sees jQuery. How would one write this to work in WordPress? I am merely swapping the boxes for images.

```js
var fadeinBox = $("#box2");
var fadeoutBox = $("#box1");

function fade() {
    fadeinBox.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
    fadeoutBox.stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000, function() {
        var temp = fadeinBox;
        fadeinBox = fadeoutBox;
        fadeoutBox = temp;
        setTimeout(fade, 1000);
    });
}

fade();
```

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

#wrapper {position: relative;}

#box1 {background-color: #F00;}
#box2 {background-color: #00F;  display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the example I found on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3XwZv/)

Comment: instead of using `$` try with `jQuery`.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work

Comment: Where have you included this script in WordPress?

Comment: In the footer of the site

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
      var fadeinBox = $("#box2");
      var fadeoutBox = $("#box1");

    function fade() {
    fadeinBox.stop(true, true).fadeIn(2000);
    fadeoutBox.stop(true, true).fadeOut(2000, function() {
    var temp = fadeinBox;
    fadeinBox = fadeoutBox;
    fadeoutBox = temp;
    setTimeout(fade, 1000);
    });
   }

  fade();
   }); </script>
```

Comment: Try above jquery code with your all other code i,e html, css ...hope it helps you...

Comment: Then you put this code b/w <head> and </head>, then try.

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress you have to create a js file and enqueue this js file in your theme's functions.php like this:

```
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jsfile', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/yourjs.js", '', '', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

Please put newly created js file in js folder in your theme directory.

Answer (score 0):

like Atif tariq said, you need to use the  wp_enqueue_script function to include a jQuery script in WordPress.

Alternatively, you can download a plugin called "Add Script To Post" by *arefly*, and activate it. It will allow you to execute script directly in page or post by putting your jQuery code between [script][/script] (instead of ).

Note: you will also need to load the jQuery API before executing you code, preferably before and outside of [script]...[/script]. use this line to load it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```